# How to instantiate a shared resource in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I noticed that jUnit runs the constructor of my test class for each method being tested.  Here's an example:

```
public class TestTest {
    protected BigUglyResource bur;
    public TestTest(){
        bur=new BigUglyResource();
        System.out.println("TestTest()");
    }
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        System.out.printf("test1()\n");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        System.out.printf("test2()\n");
    }
    @Test
    public void test3(){
        System.out.printf("test3()\n");
    }
}
```

Gives the following result:

```
TestTest()
test1()
TestTest()
test2()
TestTest()
test3()
```

Calling the constructor to BigUglyResource is too time-consuming,  I'd prefer to build it only once.  I know you can use @BeforeClass to run a method once, but @BeforeClass is only for static methods.  Static methods can't access a class property like BigUglyResource in the example above.  Other than building a Singleton, what options are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you declare the `BigUglyResource` static? This is how I normally do it.

```
private static BigUglyResource bur;

@BeforeClass
public static void before(){
   bur=new BigUglyResource();
}
```

Comment: I'm surprized this didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could make "bur" static:

```
protected static BigUglyResource bur;
```

And use @BeforeClass.

Answer (score 0):

For JUnit5 users: you have to use `@BeforeAll` annotation instead of `@BeforeEach`, the rest stays the same as in bruno's and Russ'es answers.

```
private static BigUglyResource bur;

@BeforeAll
public static void before(){
   bur=new BigUglyResource();
}
```